# Is there a physical motivation to study finite fields?

Tags: mathematics, partition-function, complex-numbers, analyticity, algebraic-geometry

Clearly finite groups are of immense value in physics and these are also substructures of fields. However I never came across any computations involving finite fields at university and so I never learned about them explicitly.

> Are there some physical motivations to study [finite fields/Galois fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_fields)?
>
> Can I study these objects in a physical context?

I'm coming to ask this question because I'm interested in [generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) (in a physical contexts), and hence [zeta-functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function). I now and them come across things like the [Weil conjectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures) which mathematicans seem to love, but in trying to understand these I see that I miss the background.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44681/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26856/2451

Answer (score 2):

Finite fields are essential for constructing [MUBs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_unbiased_bases) (see [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916%2889%2990322-9) by Wootters and Fields). Also, dealing with quantum error correcting codes (for qubits) is essentially the same as doing linear algebra over GF(4) because of the way [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) behave (see [arXiv:0904.2557](http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.2557) or [arXiv:quant-ph/9608006](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9608006)).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer for the zeta-functions or Weil-conjectures but one Finite field comes into sight as answer to your question.

Quaternions discovered by Hamilton have four unity vectors with a strange multiplication. Frobenius did work on this four element pseudo field.

It is a almost field but lacks commutativity   A x B = B x A

There is one real unity vector and three imaginary ones.

The three a part build vectors (not discussing the imaginary nature of the unity vectors) and are used in threedimensional geometry and quantum mechanics.

Comment: Thanks for bumping the thread, but quaternions are no finite field. They contain a subset isomorphic to the reals and these are not even countable. The *four* is the dimension of the quaternions as a vector space. If you think about it, by your definition, the real numbers are a field with one element. PS: I did link to the finite fields Wikipedia page in the question.

Comment: @NickKidman This answer applies to the [quaternion group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group), which is indeed finite but is of course not a field.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: There is a nice [list of the small finite groups Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups#List_of_small_non-abelian_groups). There is also a mad person who makes a [personal wiki on groups and their properties](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Quaternion_group).