# Can there be an **essential topic** in physics which cannot be archimedean?

Tags: mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, mathematics, complex-numbers, specific-reference

In physics it seems everything is explained with $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ typed entitites.

1. Is there anything in or that would be in future in physics that would need the utility of $p$-adics in an **essential way**?
2. Why is everything explainable with only $\mathbb C$ in an **essential way** even though there are far more numbers of form involving $\mathbb Q_p$ completions $\mathbb C_p$?

Is there a fundamental reference?

Comment: There are p-adic mathematical physics, actually I have such a book on my shelf that I still haven't found the time to read.

Comment: Quaternions appear in Sp(N) (so standard gauge theories, but more importantly in SUSY, with its hyperkäler moduli spaces). $p$-adics appear in the classification of lattices (so String Theory, Condensed Matter Physics, etc). The question is way too broad.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107290/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/361650/2451 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15252/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist The very fact you have not read it makes it not essential for your working knowledge.

Comment: As of your latest edit, it seems like [what you meant to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) was why are $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ more physically helpful than $\Bbb Q_p$ and $\Bbb C_p$? I don't think you should expect every mathematical structure to be physically relevant, only [every solution to problems in an already-relevant structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totalitarian_principle).

Comment: @J.G. Numbers are numbers and there are probably essential realities to them. My post is deeper than what you are gathering here.

Comment: @T.... If you edit enough to convince those who voted to close (I wasn't one of them) that your question is deep rather than broad, maybe your question will be re-opened, which is the only way it can get another answer. Good luck.

Comment: p-adics don’t appear essentially in the description of any observable physics. They could appear in nonobservable physics, but that isn’t surprising, as then both things are just pure math.

Comment: @T.... it's in my endless reading material. :-D

Comment: It seems that the res. recom. tag does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to read more widely to encounter a broad range of number systems being useful in at least theoretical physics. I'll hyperlink to discussions of applications, but just mention the number systems themselves, as some have multiple applications.

There are uses for [$p$-adic numbers](https://cds.cern.ch/record/689731/files/0312046.pdf), [split-complex numbers](https://mathematics-abound.blogspot.com/2012/10/calculus-on-split-complex-plane.html), [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number#Applications_in_mechanics), [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Quaternions_in_physics), [split-quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-quaternion#Application_to_kinematics), [dual complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-complex_number#Representing_rigid_body_motions), [octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion#Applications), [split-octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-octonion#Applications), [dual quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_quaternion#More_on_spatial_displacements), [Clifford algebras more generally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra#Applications), and [Grassmann numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number). (For that last one, I just linked to the overall article because it frequently mentions the relevance to fermions.)

The prevalence of $\Bbb C$ can be explained, or at least half-explained, from many perspectives; Scott Aaronson has looked into why quantum mechanics runs on them in [at](https://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec9.html) [least](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=4021) [three](https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/island.pdf) long but good reads. In particular, he looks at why they $\Bbb C$ may be a sweet spot between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb H$.

Comment: The link for p-adics shows **no relevancy to essential need** for p-adics but gives a purported theory. This posting is only about p-adics and the answerer tells a long irrelevant message and I wonder why it is upvoted.

Comment: @T.... I've replaced that link with a better one, but I think you're being unfair about the rest of the answer. The OP's second question was about "far more" number systems.

Comment: by number systems I meant $\mathbb Q_p$ completions.

Comment: @T.... Then your question should have said so.

Comment: You should have read the title carefully and understood context. If unclear you should have asked clarification.

Comment: @T... I read the title *and* question carefully, and so did everyone who put your question on hold for being too broad, because at the time you implied you were interested in just about every number system there is. A few minutes ago, I changed the $p$-adic link. Is it what you wanted now, or do you want more?

Comment: How is the p-adic explanation essential when all the experimentation in the world can be explained with $\mathbb C$? You are missing the point. If I needed a few useless pointers I would have asked dumb google search. I would not have searched the database of intelligent humans by posting here.

Comment: @T.... The hostility you are exhibiting towards a good-faith answer to your question (and FWIW a good answer to the question as asked) is not helpful. Best policy is to pretend that other users deserve your respect and understanding even when their answers aren't what you are looking for.

Comment: I consider users here intelligent. I am not belittling anyone.

Comment: @T.... I think J.Murray was talking more about [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Comment: Ok I have a request can you remove your answer? This post is too messed up.

Comment: @T.... Me removing my answer won't help you, since it's unlikely this question will ever be opened. Try asking a fresh question that's much clearer than your current one. I think you'll want to make clear from the opening that you want to know whether anything in physics "requires" $\Bbb Q_p$ or $\Bbb C_p$ in at least the sense certain things currently "require" $\Bbb C$, and if so what, and if not why not? (If that's not how you intended your question, that's fine, but a new one would hopefully make clear what you're asking instead.)

Comment: @J.G. I want to delete the post.